# Correct place to keep persistence.xml in Maven web application

Tags: maven, web-applications, cassandra, persistence, kundera

I have created maven web project. Now I am trying to connect Cassandra through Kundera library.

I kept my persistence.xml in `src/main/resources/META-INF/` folder. But I am getting the following error:

```
    javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named testing
    javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:89)
    javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:60)
    kundera.ConnectServlet.connect(ConnectServlet.java:56)
    kundera.ConnectServlet.doGet(ConnectServlet.java:34)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
```

Which means it is missing `persistence.xml` only right?

My persistence.xml file contains:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
version="2.0">
<persistence-unit name="testing">
    <provider>com.impetus.kundera.KunderaPersistence</provider>     
    <properties>            
        <property name="kundera.nodes" value="localhost"/>
        <property name="kundera.port" value="9160"/>
        <property name="kundera.username" value="cassandra" />
        <property name="kundera.password" value="cassandra" />
        <property name="kundera.keyspace" value="cma"/>
        <property name="kundera.dialect" value="cassandra"/>
        <property name="kundera.ddl.auto.prepare" value="create" />
        <property name="kundera.ddl.auto.prepare" value="update" />
        <property name="kundera.client.lookup.class" value="com.impetus.client.cassandra.thrift.ThriftClientFactory" />         
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

And my Java code is:

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("testing");

EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
```

So, what is the correct solution for this?

Comment: Can you share the content of `persistence.xml`?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.I have given peristence.xml contents in the post.

Comment: One thing i observe is you have two `kundera.ddl.auto.prepare` properties set.. other things are fine..

Comment: Yes one is for create and another is for update.eevn if i remove also not working...

Comment: Sorry, i did not understand "src/main/resources as source folder.. right?". can you please explain briefly what you are asking for?

Comment: Can you share the detailed structure of your project ?

Comment: How can i share you?

Comment: Can you share a sample project at kundera@impetus.co.in

Comment: Though i was not able to send zip file through my gmail account, i have uploaded sample project here http://www.filedropper.com/kundera-webapp_1 , can you please check with that.

Comment: @Vijaya any progress on that?